# How to use Redis in php?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I installed redis 2.8.12 and configured phpredis. Then I called redis instance in php class. But there is no result, can you help me?

```
public function __construct() {

        try {
            echo ':) ';
            $newRedis = new Redis();
            echo ':P ';
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e -> getMessage();
        }



    }
```

this printed :), not printed :P

Comment: I installed redis 2.8.12 but when ctrl+click Redis() it starts // Start of redis v.2.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if your php redis module is loaded by checking in phpinfo() ? Also, if your redis server is running properly and on which port and if configured using password you are supplying same while initiating the connection ?

Comment: where i have to see in phpinfo() about redis

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use RedisException class to debug your redis connection.

```
try{
  if( $socket = fsockopen( $host, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr )){
    if( $errorNo ){
      throw new RedisException(“Socket cannot be opened”);
   }    
  }
}catch( Exception $e ){
  echo $e -> getMessage( );
}
```

I will elaborate on the answer once you are able to give an exception or an error.